# Using Facebook app install ads with iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, ads

Facebook for Developers says I have to switch the app to "development mode" so I can use app install ads, but it also says, users can't use Facebook login in development mode.

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: I don't think you need Facebook Login to make ads work, it should work automatically with you facebook app credentials, you might need to submit Facebook app for Review(Right now Facebook is not reviewing any app).

Comment: Oh, the problem is that I already use Facebook login and _now_ I want app install ads. Facebook tells me I need set the app into development mode, buz wont this prevent my login from working?